# Get Sequelize.js ENUM Values from Already Defined Model

Tags: node.js, enums, sequelize.js

How do we get the ENUM values of a model after defining it in Sequelize.js?

For example, we define our model as:

```
sequelize.define('model', {
  states: {
    type:   Sequelize.ENUM,
    values: ['active', 'pending', 'deleted']
  }
})
```

How do we get the pre-defined `['active', 'pending' ,'deleted']` values from this model?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The ENUM values in a schema can be found in the `rawAttributes` property of the model.

```
var Model = sequelize.define('model', {
  states: {
    type:   Sequelize.ENUM,
    values: ['active', 'pending', 'deleted']
  }
});

console.log(Model.rawAttributes.states.values);
// logs ['active', 'pending', 'deleted'] in console
```

Answer (score 1):

Create JavaScript Enum Object like that

```
module.exports.BookingStatus = Object.freeze({
  Done: 'Done',
  Pending: 'Pending',
  Rejected: 'Rejected'
});
```

Next, is to create sequalize Schema having enum

```
const Booking = sequalize.define(
  'booking',
  {
    customerId : DataTypes.STRING,
    bookingStatus : {
      type : DataTypes.ENUM,
      values : Object.values(this.BookingStatus),
      defaultValue :  this.BookingStatus.Pending
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sequelize.define('model', {
  states: {
    type:   Sequelize.ENUM('active', 'pending', 'deleted')
  }
})
```

source: https://sebhastian.com/sequelize-enum/