# How to define certain values for column in Postgres sql?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have field Gender in my table. It should contain any one of 'M,F,O' values only. How to make it possible?

I'm using sequalize ORM in node.js for postgres, how to do it in sequalize?

Comment: You *could* try using an ENUM https://stackoverflow.com/a/22366931/742129

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_gender
    check ( gender in ('M', 'F', 'O') );
```

Note:  This check constraint allows `NULL` values.  You can define the column as `NOT NULL` to disallow those.